# I/O error: Address not available (os error 99) in dockerised next(with Prisma)/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, prisma

#### Some Overhead

I am writing a web app using Next.js 13, Prisma and a MongoDB database. To keep the project consistent between developers, I have dockerised the project so far using docker-compose.

#### The issue

When I run `docker-compose up`, it all runs fine. I can run the `npx prisma` commands from my own terminal just fine with expected output. I can connect to my MongoDB database from MongoDB Compass and from within the `mongo` container.

The issue is that when I try and perform any actions on the MongoDB instance from within the `next-app` container (either `npx prisma` commands that interact with the database) or by requests using the prisma client, I get the following error output (or slight variations of it). The intent is to be able to use the prisma client and npx cli tool to be able interact with the MongoDB instance from within the next-app container (the purpose of sharing a `common-network` network in the docker-compose

```
⨯ PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:
Raw query failed. Code: `unknown`. Message: `Kind: Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Set Name: rs0, Max Set Version: 1, Max Election ID: 7fffffff0000000000000002, Servers: [ { Address: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: Address not available (os error 99), labels: {} } ] }, labels: {}`
    at Cn.handleRequestError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:123:6817)
    at Cn.handleAndLogRequestError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:123:6206)
    at Cn.request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:123:5926)
    at async l (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:128:9968)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/user/route.ts:14:18)
    at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62361 {
  code: 'P2010',
  clientVersion: '5.5.0',
  meta: {
    code: 'unknown',
    message: 'Kind: Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Set Name: rs0, Max Set Version: 1, Max Election ID: 7fffffff0000000000000002, Servers: [ { Address: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: Address not available (os error 99), labels: {} } ] }, labels: {}'
  }
}
```

I have a little experience with docker and docker-compose, but am totally new to MongoDB. Any assistance with examples would be greatly appreciated. If I have missed anything out that might be important to help, then please comment and let me know, and I will edit this question to include it.

#### My Prisma schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

[... Models ...]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: ./next-app
    command: npm run dev
    container_name: app
    env_file: ./next-app/.env
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./next-app:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/.next
    networks:
      - common-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build: ./mongodb_rs
    restart: always
    env_file: ./mongodb_rs/.env
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
    networks:
      - common-network

volumes:
  mongo:
    name: "mongo"

networks:
  common-network:
    driver: bridge
```

#### .envs

```
# next-app
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/golearn?authSource=admin"

# mongodb_rs
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017/golearn?authSource=admin"
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=golearn
MONGO_REPLICA_PORT=27017
MONGO_REPLICA_HOST=localhost
```

#### Mongo Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:4

# we take over the default & start mongo in replica set mode in a background task
ENTRYPOINT mongod --port $MONGO_REPLICA_PORT --replSet rs0 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 & MONGOD_PID=$!; \
INIT_REPL_CMD="rs.initiate({ _id: 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: '$MONGO_REPLICA_HOST:$MONGO_REPLICA_PORT' }] })"; \
INIT_USER_CMD="db.getUser('$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME') || db.createUser({ user: '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME', pwd: '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD', roles: [ 'root' ] })"; \
until (mongo admin --port $MONGO_REPLICA_PORT --eval "$INIT_REPL_CMD && $INIT_USER_CMD"); do sleep 1; done; \
echo "REPLICA SET ONLINE"; wait $MONGOD_PID;
```

Comment: `DATABASE_URL="mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/golearn?authSource=admin"`